# CQ5 OSGi Bundle error - org.json.simple -- Cannot be resolved

Tags: java, json, maven, aem

I'm installing an OSGi bundle on my AEM environment as a jar.

During that I get the following error after installing the bundle:

```
org.json.simple -- Cannot be resolved
```

I have declared the dependency in Maven and my program is running fine on local.

My maven dependency is as follows:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
     <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
     <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Do I need to add any more dependencies to resolve the error?
I'm relatively new  to maven and this is one of the first bundle that I'm developing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OSGi Bundle status is not Active (CQ5 Maven Project) WHY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912636/osgi-bundle-status-is-not-active-cq5-maven-project-why)

Comment: Maven only helps you building the bundle, it does not take care of deploying your dependencies into the OSGi container. This has been discussed before, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912636/osgi-bundle-status-is-not-active-cq5-maven-project-why/29937645#29937645

Answer (score 4):

Change your maven bundle configuration

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>

                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile;inline=false</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>

                    </instructions>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
```

There are some transitive dependencies that it needs which should get fixed by code above

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you have to wrap this JAR into an OSGi bundle and deploy that bundle to AEM.

See this AEM Artilce that shows you how to use this JSON lib in AEM:

http://scottsdigitalcommunity.blogspot.ca/2013/06/posting-form-data-to-adobe-cq-using.html

This shows you exactly how to perform this use case.